# SmartTarget Reporting information

Tags: smarttarget

We've been discussing the creation of some SmartTarget 'reporting' with a particular customer, for example:

- How popular a promotion is
- If a specific user did not visit a promotion

I'm wondering if it's possible that SmartTarget includes similar functionality.  I don't see anything specific in the SDL Tridion documentation, but I do see there are integrations for analytics tools (namely google) within the Fredhopper documentation.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know SmartTarget/Fredhopper does not have a reporting module anymore.
However a few things come to mind related to your customer's use case:

- Using Online Marketing Explorer you can create a campaign which tracks a specific SmartTarget promotion, showing you the statistics of how the campaign performs, how many views and CTR. OME will be retired in the future, but good to use for Tridion 2011 and 2013.
- SmartTarget is a "self learning" targeting engine, this means that without creating a report, you can ingest Google or other analytics data into Fredhopper for instance once a day to be able to rank your content by popularity. After ingesting the latest analytics information, SmartTarget can display automatically the most popular/most visited items if you setup a promotion with sorting on the "number of visits" field. The key for this to work is to setup the Google analytics to track each Component Presentation individually, rather than simply tracking page views. Then you use the Fredhopper Data Manager to create the transformation used to gather analytics data from Google and append appropriately to each item in the Fredhopper index.

  In some cases, this is enough to bypass the need for a report, because content is then automatically ranked according to its CTR or number of views, hence the most viewed/most relevant content can be showed by a promotion.
- Personalization & Profiling can also help with the tracking part. You can then add a user to a specific Audience Manager segment when he/she views a particular Component Presentation, to then drive targeting based on segments. The reporting side of things would be custom in this case, but the data is available via API. You would know if a user has not visited a promotion for instance when they do not have a specific tracking keyword in their profile e.g. "Viewed Valentine's day Campaign" keyword.

Comment: thanks Philippe, some great thoughts - when you say 'ingest' is this simply to put analytics information into the ADF and make this available as a trigger type?

Comment: You're welcome! I mean enriching the FH items with analytics information, using a Data Manager transformation (Pentaho). Pentaho is an ETL tool (looks like it is not open source anymore) which you can use to pull Google Analytics data (actually any 3rd party data from DB, web service, file etc...) and associate this data to each indexed item in the FH index. For instance if you publish Banners CPs from Tridion to SmartTarget, and you have a Data Manager transformation each night pulling the Google Analytics data with #views for each banner, you can than add a #views field to each banner in FH.

Comment: Then in your promotion you change the sorting order to #views descending, this would show the most viewed banners first. The process to create the Data Manager transformation is quite involved, usually done by FH Professional Services, but if you have some time you can pull it off. It brings SmartTarget ROI to a whole higher level! Documentation is here: https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Use+3rd+party+analytics+data

Comment: Data Manager is available for download in the FH learning center https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Tools+and+Downloads

Comment: thanks phillipe this is all a tonne of great information, processing through it now :)